# How to insert image files in Electron + React.js + Webpack desktop app package for Mac OS

Tags: macos, reactjs, electron, electron-packager

I am building a desktop application for Mac OS with Electron + React + Webpack mode.
When I build a Electron desktop app as production version, I would like to insert some image files in the setup file(Test.app and Test.dmg) and use the image as following:

```
let Logo = process.resourcesPath + '/logo.png';

class Loading extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <img className={styles.logo} src={Logo} />
          ...
       </div>
      );
  }
}
```

But this app can't get the image because the logo.png file didn't be include in Test.app/Content/Resources/ directory when I run 'npm run package' command and build a Test.app for Mac OS.

Here, the issue is as following:

> GET file:///Applications/Test.app/Contents/Resources/logo.png
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I would like to insert this image file in my Test.app package for Mac OS.

Please help me how to insert some image files into Test.app package for a Mac OS desktop application.

---

#### webpack.config.base.js

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { dependencies as externals } from './app/package.json';

export default {
  externals: Object.keys(externals || {}),

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      }
    }]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1114
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

---

#### webpack.config.production.js

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import validate from 'webpack-validator';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

export default validate(merge(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

  entry: './app/index',

  output: {
    publicPath: '../dist/'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // Extract all .global.css to style.css as is
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        )
      },

      // Pipe other styles through css modules and append to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        )
      },

      // Fonts
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?name=fonts/[hash].[ext]&limit=50000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?name=fonts/[hash].[ext]&limit=50000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[hash].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[hash].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[hash].[ext]' },

      // Images
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new BabiliPlugin({
      // Disable deadcode until https://github.com/babel/babili/issues/385 fixed
      deadcode: false,
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', { allChunks: true }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'app.html',
      template: 'app/app.html',
      inject: false
    })
  ],

  target: 'electron-renderer'
}));
```

---

#### webpack.config.electron.js

```
/**
 * Build config for electron 'Main Process' file
 */

import webpack from 'webpack';
import validate from 'webpack-validator';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

export default validate(merge(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './main.development'],

  // 'main.js' in root
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './main.js'
  },

  plugins: [
      deadcode: false,
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ],

  target: 'electron-main',

  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  }
}));
```

---

#### scripts section of package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 node --trace-warnings ./test/runTests.js",
    "test-all": "npm run lint && npm run flow && npm run test && npm run build && npm run test-e2e",
    "test-watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "test-e2e": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 node --trace-warnings ./test/runTests.js e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --format=node_modules/eslint-formatter-pretty .",
    "lint-fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "lint-styles": "stylelint app/*.css app/components/*.css --syntax scss",
    "hot-updates-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.renderer.dev.js",
    "build": "concurrently \"npm run copy-images\" \"npm run build-main\" \"npm run build-renderer\"",
    "build-dll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.main.prod.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "build-renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.renderer.prod.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./app/",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "flow": "flow",
    "flow-typed": "rm -rf flow-typed && flow-typed install --overwrite || true",
    "start-hot-renderer": "cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill ./app/main.development",
    "postinstall": "concurrently \"npm run flow-typed\" \"npm run build-dll\" \"install-app-deps\" \"node node_modules/fbjs-scripts/node/check-dev-engines.js package.json\"",
    "dev": "cross-env START_HOT=1 npm run hot-updates-server",
    "package": "npm run build && build --publish never",
    "package-win": "npm run build && build --win --x64",
    "package-linux": "npm run build && build --linux",
    "package-all": "npm run build && build -mwl",
    "cleanup": "mop -v",
    "copy-images": "cp -Rf app/shared/images/ app/dist/images/"
  },
  "browserslist": "electron 1.4",
  "build": {
    "productName": "Test",
    "appId": "org.Test",
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/",
      "app.html",
      "main.js",
      "main.js.map",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 220
        },
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 220,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "AppImage"
      ]
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Are you using some loader, such as `file-loader` or `url-loader`? It would be great if you post your webpack config file.

Comment: OK. I'll post the webpack ocnfig file soon.

Comment: I posted webpack config files above.

Comment: Try to import you image with something like this: `import Logo from 'path/to/logo.png';`. (replace `path/to/` with the real path to the file).

Comment: It's possible when this electron desktop app run as development mode by running 'npm run dev' command on Mac OS.

Comment: Both  

import Logo from 'path/to/logo.png';

and 

let Logo = path.resolve('./') + '/resources/logo.png';

 is possible when this electron desktop app run 'npm run dev' command for development mode or run 'npm run start' command for production mode in Terminal on Mac OS.
But when I double click Test.app which was built by 'npm run package' command on Mac OS, this app didn't find the path of the image file.

Comment: Finally, I need to use this image path in Test.app for Mac OS.

Comment: For example, I copied this logo.png into [Test_project_code]/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/ directory and ran 'npm run dev' or 'npm run start' command. 
Then, this code
let Logo = process.resourcesPath + '/logo.png';
got the image file correctly and displayed.

As this, I would like to include logo.png file into Test.app/Contents/Resources directory when I build this Test.app desktop app with 'npm run package' command.

Comment: Try to use `file-loader` to load images instead of `url-loader`. And instead of using `import`, like a said on the previous comment, use `const Logo = require("file-loader!path/to/logo.png");`. It's worth checking out the `file-loader` docs here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Comment: I added below code in webpack.config.development.js file:
module {
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=resources/img/&outputPath=app/img/"
      }
}

But when I run 'npm run package' command, the img directory and image files don't be included  in Test.app/Contents/Resources/ directory, yet.

Comment: Hmmm... you can try to create an npm task to copy the images folder to the output path before running the `package` command.

Comment: I'm not clear yet. Please let me know with example, in more details.

Comment: probably, there's a `scripts` section in your `package.json`. create the following task: `"copy-images": "cp -R path/to/images dist"`. Then, in the `package` task, run the task `copy-images` before the `build` command. Something like this: `"package": "npm run copy-images && build ..."`.

Comment: When I run "npm run build" command with "npm run copy-images", the image directory was copied into "dist" directory. 
But when I run "npm run package" command, the image directory don't be included into Test.app/Contents/Resources directory, yet.

Comment: Please, show me your `scripts` section...

Comment: My script section are as following:

Comment: post in your original question, please...

Comment: I posted my script section of package.json file in my original question, again. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

after electron app installed, it put all the source code and resource files into a **.asar** package. so to insert any image, u have to use a directory outside of app.
Generally this directory can be a Document folder.

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
let tempFolder =path.join( remote.app.getPath("documents"), 'AppFiles');
```

use the **tempFolder** directory to save image.